# Can I estimate the variance of MLE estimator?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics

Suppose I want to test if a coin is fair. I toss the coin 10 times and get the following outcomes:
HHTTHTHHTH.  The log-likelihood function is $\ell(P_H:<H,H,T,T,H,T,H,H,T,H>)=6logP_H+4log(1-P_H)$. Maximum Likelihood Estimation will give $P_H=0.6$. Can I estimate the variance of this estimator??

Comment: Yes. There are some nice theorems about the variance of the MLE. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Efficiency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did this for an assignment a couple years ago and just remembered.

More generally, consider the likelihood for a binomial process

$$\mathcal{L}(p)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
n y
\end{array}\right) p^{n y}(1-p)^{n-n y}$$

The log-likelihood is

$$ \ell(p)=n y \log (p)+(n-n y) \log (1-p)$$

The Score function (first derivative of the log-lik) is

$$ \mathcal{S}(p)=\frac{n y}{p}-\frac{n-n y}{1-p}$$

Which is 0 when $y=p$.  To get the variance of this estimator, we need to take the derivative of the score.

$$\mathcal{S}^{\prime}(p)=-\frac{n y}{p^{2}}-\frac{n-n y}{(1-p)^{2}}$$

The fisher information is then the negative expectation of this

$$\mathcal{I}(p)=-\mathbb{E}\left(\mathcal{S}^{\prime}(\hat{p})\right)=\frac{n}{p(1-p)}$$

Assuming mild regularity conditions are satisfied, maximum likelihood theory tell us

$$\mathcal{I}(\hat{p})^{1 / 2}(\hat{p}-p) \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

which implies

$$\hat{p} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(p, \frac{p(1-p)}{n}\right)$$

And so use of Slutsky's theorem implies the variance is $$\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n$$